# What is the advantage of using two capacitors in the DC links rather just one?

Tags: dc, boost

What is the advantage of using one big capacitor vs two smaller ones as DC link?

For example, one 0.5 farad capacitor vs two 0.25 farad capacitors.

Comment: It depends on the application I suspect.

Comment: The advantage or disadvantage depends on a lot of things. Why do you ask? Is this a school assignment?

Comment: It is for an assignment, it would be the DC link between a boost converter and an inverter

Comment: the title question does not match the question in the post

Comment: A 0.5 F capacitor is enormous.

Comment: Peter: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 11):

A bunch of reasons come to mind:

- Cost: larger caps do not necessarily have lower $/µF cost
- Height
- Inductance: it is roughly proportional to pin spacing multiplied by standoff height, which is the area of the current loop. So, physically smaller caps have lower inductance. Several caps in parallel will divide the total inductance by the number of caps. Huge caps with screw terminals have correspondingly huge inductance, which is not well suited for modern high frequency switching circuits, and they require more labor for assembly.
- Square cube law: The cap is air cooled via its outer surface. Physically smaller caps have more cooling surface per volume and per µF. Also larger caps can get hotter inside before the heat finds its way out through all the layers. So a number of smaller caps will offer higher ripple current rating, if the limiting factor is self-heating.
- Reliability: heavy components tend to fall off the board in case of shock. Several caps glued together with the usual squirt of silicone caulk work as a team to hold to the board with many pins.
- Ease of insertion: perhaps the pick and place machine has a weight/size limit.
- Flexibility: several models can use the same PCB, with the number of caps adjusted depending on the model's output power. Stocking fewer values in greater quantities lowers costs.

Comment: Great set of answers, just like the set of capacitors!

Comment: Way overlooked factor is the cooling, so many caps die a premature death because of that

Comment: Parallel capacitors have, overall, lower ESR in general.

Answer (score 6):

There may be several reasons to choose one over the other. In most commercial VFDs and servos that I have seen multiple capacitors seems to be the choice. I suspect that this is because of height constraints in the packaging. (Taller caps would make the drive wider and take up more panel space.)

[image]

*Figure 1. What appears to be an extreme case! Image source: [Baiza Automation](https://baizaautomation.com/variable-frequency-drive-vfd-repair-process/).*

Other factors may include equivelant series resistance (ESR), current handling capability of the PCB and availability. (Even if one large capacitor was available from one vendor the manufacturer may want a second source and so choose a standard package.)

Comment: In my practice the dominant consideration is the ac current. It is never enough, sometimes a straight calculation requires crazy numbers of capacitors, so we end up having on paper less ac current capability than intended.

Answer (score 4):

> *What is the advantage of using two capacitors in the DC links rather
> just one?*

$$\boxed{\text{Short answer: increased RMS or ripple current}}$$

When you mention DC link capacitors I presume you mean this type of component: -

[image]

And, these polypropylene capacitors are extremely good at supplying high surge currents. That to me meets 25% of the job description for a DC link capacitor. The other 75% is voltage rating, capacitance and, RMS current.

So, although these capacitors are great for peak current: -

[image]

They are not so great on RMS current: -

[image]

And, many applications require massive surge current handling AND, a fairly decent RMS current handling capability. So, paralleling 2 or more is the route to take. For instance, on one job, I needed to parallel 42 of them: -

[image]

I'm not going to go into further details because it's IP but, the general idea is clear; you would parallel capacitors like this to increase the ripple current or the RMS current. The hidden advantage is that the effective ESR and ESL of the combined arrangement is very low.

> *it would be the DC link between a boost converter and an inverter –
> Peter Lyngbye*

That's pretty much where I had to use them. Boost to several hundred volts feeding four H-bridge driven transformers.

Comment: Film capacitors are generally more expensive per unit of capacitance, so they are usually used rather frugally in parallel with higher capacitance aluminum electrolytics. This may be especially true for single phase input VFDs where the capacitors must hold minimum bus voltage between rectified voltage peaks.

Comment: @PStechPaul it depends what "usually" means. It seems that my "usual" is different to your "usual".